# mapping resources from context

Tags: java, spring, servlets, contextpath

I want to map my folder in resources folder from context
for example, in context.xml (I want to map files from src/main/resources)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/resources/**">staticResources</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="staticResources" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/resources/myFolder/</value>
            <value>/resources/</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In `myFolder` there are many sub-folders with files and more sub-folders
but firebug says error 404 and that such resources cannot be found

Answer (score 1):

It will be better to do this through `mvc` namespace -

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/,classpath:/resources/myFolder" mapping="/resources/**" />
```

then your static resources should be accessible from `http://serverurl/contextpath/resources/*`